# sql full text search with nullable parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, contains

We would like to work with full-text search but keep the incoming parameters in our procedure null-able. In this example `@Street` can have a value like `Heuvel` or can be `NULL`.

Working this out in a query is something that doesn't work.

1. `heuvel*` gives all the rows that are expected.
2. `*` gives zero rows while other threads on forums say that it will give all rows
3. `street = isnull(@street, street)` gives all rows

Knowing all the above I would think this query would work. It does but it's VERY slow.

When I execute the or clause separately then the query is fast.

```
Declare @Street nvarchar(50)= '"heuvel*"'
Declare @InnerStreet nvarchar(50) =  '"'+ isnull(@Street, '')  +'*"';

SELECT *
FROM Address
WHERE street = isnull(@street, street) or CONTAINS(street, @InnerStreet)
```

Now the question is, how to work with full-text search and null-able parameters?

Comment: In addition to `@Street`, how many other nullable parameters are there for you stored proc?

Comment: There are multiple nullable parameters in the original query. The query in this thread is a simplyfied version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. @street is either NULL or has a value.

```
declare @streetWildcard nvarchar(50) = '"' + @street + '*"'
SELECT *
FROM Address
WHERE (@street is NULL) or CONTAINS(street, @streetWildcard)
```

If the performance is still bad then the execution plan may not be short circuiting the WHERE condition. In that case, try this instead.

```
if (@street is NULL) begin
    SELECT *
    FROM Address
end
else begin
    declare @streetWildcard nvarchar(50) = '"' + @street + '*"'
    SELECT *
    FROM Address
    WHERE CONTAINS(street, @streetWildcard)
end
```

Comment: I get a syntac error on the + in "CONTAINS(street, '"' + street + '*"')". When i put the '"' + street + '*"' in new declared parameter the query runs but very slow.

Comment: I updated my answer to fix the syntax error and address the performance problem. If the Address table has many rows and columns then consider selecting only the necessary columns and perhaps limit or page the results.

Comment: The part with the if else works but making my query like that is gone be very long. Like i mentioned the full query has multiple nullable parameters. If i need to write a query for every single nullable parameter in a if else funtion it's not gonne be readable or maintainable anymore.